# How to use EfficientNet Lite models as backbone for keypoint regression?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I would like to employ EfficientNet Lite 0 model as a backbone to perform a keypoint regression task. However, I get stuck at loading the model from the either Tensorflow Hub or the official GitHub repository. Could you please explain how can I:

- import such model in Tensorflow with checkpoints from ImageNet
- modify the last layers of the network
- modify the loss according to my task
- retrain the network

I am looking forward to apply Efficient Lite since I would like to convert everything to TF Lite.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Lite currently doesn't support EfficientNet Lite, but they do support mobile (CPU & GPU) friendly CenterNet. See [this Colab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/centernet_on_device.ipynb) that demonstrates how to use this model.

Commands to convert the keypoints model:

```
# Get mobile-friendly CenterNet for Keypoint detection task.
# See TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo for more details:
# https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md

wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20210210/centernet_mobilenetv2fpn_512x512_coco17_kpts.tar.gz
tar -xf centernet_mobilenetv2fpn_512x512_coco17_kpts.tar.gz
rm centernet_mobilenetv2fpn_512x512_coco17_kpts.tar.gz*

# Export the intermediate SavedModel that outputs 10 detections & takes in an 
# image of dim 320x320.
# Modify these parameters according to your needs.

python models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py \
  --pipeline_config_path=centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/pipeline.config \
  --trained_checkpoint_dir=centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/checkpoint \
  --output_directory=centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/tflite \
  --centernet_include_keypoints=true \
  --keypoint_label_map_path=centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/label_map.txt \
  --max_detections=10 \
  --config_override=" \
    model{ \
      center_net { \
        image_resizer { \
          fixed_shape_resizer { \
            height: 320 \
            width: 320 \
          } \
        } \
      } \
    }"

tflite_convert --output_file=centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/model.tflite \
  --saved_model_dir=centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/tflite/saved_model
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I was looking at the pipeline.config of the CenterNet network and I saw there is the need to provide keypoints permutation in case the image is flipped. So my question is, if my object is represented in many different poses, will the network be able to identify the keypoints as well or the images shall all be taken from more or less the same pose? I mean, if my object is rotated of 90° between an image and another is it a problem for the network?

Comment: It should work. You can use the colab code with your custom image and see if it works.